# AngularJS Error: $interpolate:interr Interpolation Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get a youtube video inserted into my website with AngularJS, but I keep getting the same error:

```
Error: $interpolate:interr Interpolation Error
```

Why do I get this error and how can I get rid of it? All I want is to insert the video...

**App.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'duScroll', 'duParallax', 'angularFileUpload', 'ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'
]);

myApp.filter('youtube', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        var videoLink = val;
        var watch = val.indexOf("?v=") + 3;
        var playlist = val.indexOf('&') + 1;

        if (playlist > 0) {
            return $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl('//www.youtube.com/embed/' + val.substring(watch, playlist));
        } else {
            return $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl('//www.youtube.com/embed/' + val.substring(watch, videoLink.length));
        }
    };
}]);
```

**index.jade**

```
iframe(ng-if="story.media.video" src="{{ story.media.video | youtube }}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen)
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case it would [seem simpler to whitelist](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider) the youtube embed path and get rid of the filter.

Also, you should also use `ng-src` instead of `src` for the iframe.

```
myApp.config(["$sceDelegateProvider", function($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',
        "http://www.youtube.com/embed/**"
    ]);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this Jquery basic:

```
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bSMInVPIE8o?autoplay=1"
$JQ('iframe').attr('src',src);
```

Comment: You should update your answer so that code is appropriately in either inline formatting or in code blocks (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)