# Angular IFrame ng-src: Interpolate Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I am trying to embed a Google map inside an `iframe` using:

```
<div ng-repeat="event in ctrl.events">
    <iframe src="{{'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=(' + event.location.latitude + '%2C' + event.location.longitude + ')&zoom=12&key=API_KEY'}}">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

However I get:

```
Error: $interpolate:interr Interpolation Error
```

My data set is in the form

```
$scope.events = 
[
    { 
        location : { 
            longitude: 1.1,
            latitude: -1.1
        }
    }
]
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried `ng-src` but I get the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS Error: $interpolate:interr Interpolation Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101219/angularjs-error-interpolateinterr-interpolation-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to allow the maps URL in your app's config like this:

```
myApp.config(["$sceDelegateProvider", function($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        // Allow same origin resource loads.
        "self",
        // Allow loading from Google maps
        "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place**"
    ]);
}]);
```

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider):

> The $sceDelegateProvider provider allows developers to configure the
>   $sceDelegate service. This allows one to get/set the whitelists and
>   blacklists used to ensure that the URLs used for sourcing Angular
>   templates are safe. Refer $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist
>   and $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlBlacklist

**See a working example below**

(Of course, key is wrong so Map will complain)

```js
var myApp = angular.module("sa", []);

myApp.config(["$sceDelegateProvider",
  function($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(["self",
      "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place**"
    ]);
  }
]);

myApp.controller("foo", function($scope) {
  $scope.events = [{
    location: {
      longitude: 1.1,
      latitude: -1.1
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="foo">
  <div ng-repeat="event in events">
    <iframe src="{{'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=(' + event.location.latitude + '%2C' + event.location.longitude + ')&zoom=12&key=API_KEY'}}">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*://www.google.com/maps/** did it for me:

```
angular.module('app', []).config(function($sceDelegateProvider){

$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    "*://www.google.com/maps/**"
]);
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may pick the images or iframe sources from public ips or domain names directly. In that case, you can also disable the blacklisting of all the URLs with the following code snippet.

```
var myApp = angular.module("sa", []);

myApp.config(function($sceProvider) {
  $sceProvider.enabled(false);
});
```